# Script no longer running

Tags: javascript

This is a script that was working on line and still is on my production PC.
For some reason it is no longer working. It seems to never return a status of "200". So never completes. I suspect it is the providers fault somehow, but no idea what or why.

```
function loadComents(selected_video_id){
if(selected_video_id == 0){
document.getElementById("videoComents").innerHTML = '<div align="center"><font size="+2">No coments for Play List</font></div>';
} else {
// Create our XMLHttpRequest object
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
var url = "video_coments.php";
var vars = "selected_video_id="+selected_video_id;
hr.open("POST", url, true);
// Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
// Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("videoComents").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
}
// Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
document.getElementById("videoComents").innerHTML = '<div align="center"><font size="+2">processing...</font><br /><br /></div>';
}
}
```

My console gives this.

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3.
```

If this code is outdated, can someone help with a better one that still works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All seems to be working again......

I think it was my hosting providers fault. I put a request in, and the next day it was fine. Though they claim nothing was wrong.